# JS/jQ Select Edge Between Table Cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-click-event

I want to create a script that allows resizing columns by dragging the edge between columns in the header column. For this, I need to know when the mouse is clicking between the columns ±10px on the X axis. How can I get this information or event?